# WPF Toolkit MaskTextBox Binding Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

I have a simple control that has a masked text box:

```
xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit/extended"
...
<extToolkit:MaskedTextBox Mask="000-000-000" Text="{Binding SerialNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I also have a key binding on the control:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" Gesture="Enter" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

The problem is when SearchCommand is executed I need the value they entered in the masked text box as the criteria for the search.  With a regular text box this is no problem but apparently the `MaskedTextBox`  control doesn't play well with `PropertyChanged UpdateSourceTrigger`.

If I click someplace else (so it looses focus) and then press enter it works, but obviously I don't want to have to do that. Are there any good workarounds for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must bind your property to the Value property not the Text.

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox&referringTitle=Documentation